# form submission in Drupal

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-forms

i have made a custom module for form in drupal using dupal API,and made a table in my database
What i want is to save the value of drop down box instead of it's index into database...my .module file is:

```
<?php
function form_test_menu() {
$items['formtest'] = array(
    'title' => 'Form Test',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('form_test_form'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
);
return $items;
```

}

```
function form_test_form($form,&$form_submit) {
$form['name'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Name'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
);
$form['college'] = array(
    '#title' => t('College/University'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
);
$form['education'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Education'),
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#description' => 'Select your higher education .',
    '#options' => array(t('--- SELECT ---'), t('B.tech'), t('MCA'), t('MBA'),t('Graduate')),
    '#required' => TRUE,
);
$form['percentage'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Percentage/CGPA'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
);
$form['application'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Job Applied'),
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => array(t('---select---'),t('Web Developer'),t('Web Designer'),t('SEO'),t('Marketing')),
    '#required' => TRUE,
);


$form['submit'] = array(
    '#value' => 'Submit',
    '#type' => 'submit',
);
return $form;
```

}

```
function form_test_form_submit($form, $form_state) {
global $user;
// Here u can insert Your custom form values into your custom table.
db_insert('drupal')
    ->fields(array(
        'name' => $form_state['values']['name'],
        'college' => $form_state['values']['college'],
        'education' => $form_state['values']['education'],
        'percentage' => $form_state['values']['percentage'],
        'application' => $form_state['values']['application'],

    ))->execute();
drupal_set_message("successfully saved data");
```

}
?>

All are in one file(.module)....any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to pass options array from one function to another. To achieve that use the second argument of "form_test_form" and "form_test_form_submit" functions.

```
function form_test_form($form,&$form_submit) {
  $form_submit['myoptions'] = array(' select', 'option1' .....
}
```

Then

```
function form_test_form_submit($form,&$form_state) {    
 $myoptions = $form_state['myoptions']; etc ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @progzy....i'm done with it..can you please guide me towards somenice tutorials on data retrival from database in drupal 7?...i have done that with php but the same is not working with drupal

Comment: OK. Please validate the answer if it's ok for you.
For the other question open a new question please :)